# What is the difference between doView() and render() functions in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet

What is the actual difference between `doView()` and `render()` functions in Liferay? and also what is the difference between `renderRequest` and `resourceRequest`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`doView()` = to handle render requests when in VIEW mode.

`render()` = This method invokes the `doDispath()` method and sets the title of the portlet by using `getTitle()` method. Then it invokes one of `doView()`, `doEdit()`, `doHelp()`, etc. depending of the portlet mode specified in the `RenderRequest`.

---

Again, RenderRequest is when you want to handle requests in the VIEW mode of the portlet. If your portlet uses additional resources to render the view (i.e. images, JavaScript files, etc.) then the JSP that renders the view will use `<portlet:resourceURL />` tags to generate valid URLs to those resources. Those URLs will be processed with a pair of `ResourceRequest` and `ResourceResponse` objects.

You can override the resource phase though but bear in mind that when you use `ResourceRequest`/`ResourceResponse` to serve, the portlet can't change the current portlet mode, window state or render parameters. And also the parameters set on the resource urls are not the render parameters and they are valid to serve only that current resource request.

Comment: What are the different modes in Liferay(example **VIEW** mode as you mentioned what does it actually refer to)? 
Can you give me link to some website where this can be clearly understood  or can you elaborate a bit more? 
I am still not clear about the above differences.

Comment: @rahulkgupta You need to go through a good tutorial on Portlets first and then on liferay, `Portlets in action` is a good book to start for the basic concepts and for liferay you can either try `Liferay in action` or Liferay wiki or Liferay documentation

Comment: How can I set liferay portlet title in ActionRequest, ActionResponse Object??